# How to pass spring.bind variable from freemaker to javascript function

Tags: javascript, spring, controller

From my controller I am passing a variable 
`model.addAttribute("valFromController", "Hello")` into freemaker file using `<@spring.bind "valFromController"/>` and now using HTML I want to pass this value from controller to javascript function defined in `<script> tags`

`<div id="valShower" onload="showVal(${valFromController})"></div>`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showVal(val){
     alert(val);
  }
</script>
```

How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link FYI.

[Refer this link for an Exmaple](https://hellokoding.com/form-data-binding-and-validation-example-with-java-spring-boot-and-freemarker/)

Example.
<@spring.bind "ModelName"/>

Comment: The above link didn't provide any information for me. I was asking for a way through which I could spring.bind value to javascript code written in same file